# urllib read() changing attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have a basic script, which is requesting websites to get the html source code.
while crawling several websites I figured out that different attributes in the source code are being represented wrong.

Example:

```
from urllib import request

opener = request.build_opener()
with opener.open("https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2") as response:
    html = response.read()
print(html)
```

I compared the results (`html` var) with the source code being represented by Chrome and Firefox.

I saw differences like these:

```
Browser                        Urllib

href='rfc2616.html'            href=\'rfc2616.html\'
rev='Section'                  rev=\'Section\'
rel='xref'                     rel=\'xref\'
id='sec4.5'                    id=\'sec4.4\'
```

It looks like `urllib` is putting backslashes here to escape code.

Is this a bug deep inside `urllib` or is there any way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responce.read()` will return a `bytes` object, when printed its escape sequences don't get interpreted, see:

```
print(b'hello\nworld') # prints b'hello\nworld'
```

You'll need to `decode` it to `str` which, when printed, evaluates the escapes correctly:

```
print(html.decode())
```